# Change text format on piecharts in google sheets api

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

We are trying to give specific format to the title of the piecharts via api. Is there any way to do it? We know that the basic charts has this feature but no in piecharts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be present in Sheets API yet as the [Chart section](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts) says

> The Sheets API does not yet grant full control of charts in Google
>   Sheets. Some chart types and certain chart settings (such as
>   background color or axis label formatting) cannot be accessed or
>   selected with the current API.

Closest thing I can find with regard to formating the title is found in Google Charts API, [Pie Chart data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format)

**titleTextStyle**
An object that specifies the title text style. The object has this format:

```
{ color: <string>,
  fontName: <string>,
  fontSize: <number>,
  bold: <boolean>,
  italic: <boolean> }
```

So it would look something like:

```
 var options = {
        title: 'Popularity of Types of Pizza',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: <string>,
            fontName: <string>,
            fontSize: <number>,
            bold: <boolean>,
            italic: <boolean> 
        },
        sliceVisibilityThreshold: .2
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: Thank's for your time. We hope that next versions will have this feature.